# How do I dynamically show and hide an entire TabContainer using DOJO?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, tabs, tabcontainer

DOJO seems to have some quirks here. I specifically need to have the TabContainer hidden when the page loads, but then become visible after the user clicks a button. The first thing I tried is setting style.display = "none" to start, and then setting style.display = "block" on the click event. Unfortunately, this only partially works- the page will render an invisible box in the right location/dimensions, but not render the actual contents. The box's contents only get rendered when triggered by something else (for example, going to a different FF tab or suspending/resuming firebug will make the box render).

If the style.display property is set to be visible on page load, everything works fine. You can toggle the display property and it shows or hides the tabcontainer properly. But if it's set to "none" on page load, it screws up.

I tried a workaround of setting the style.display property to "" in the HTML but then immediately setting it to "none" in the Javascript, but it still fails- the change occurs too soon and it needs to happen after the tabcontainer renders (which can take a second or two).

Some stripped sample code:

HTML:
    `<div id="tabContainer" dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width:500px;
    height:100px;display:none;"`>
    `</div`>

and then the Javascript to show the tab on a user click:

```
function initTabs()  
{  
var tabContainer = dojo.byId('tabContainer');  
tabContainer.style.display = 'block';  
}
```

How can I dynamically show/hide a TabContainer without having it start in the shown state?

Comment: Phase 1 is "Use jQuery". Phase 3 is Profit.

Comment: Seen that advice a few times, but I'm stuck with DOJO.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't being serious. :) It's a bit of a jibe at the whole "use jQuery" culture (although I love jQuery so...).

Answer (score 9):

There is solution for this. If you want to show TabContainer calll:

```
dijit.byId("tabContainer").domNode.style.display = 'block';
dijit.byId("tabContainer").resize();
```

and use 'none' if you want to hide TabContainer.

This works for me, but that is truth, it is not obvious :)

Comment: just an update for 1.8+,

`require(["dojo/dom-style"], function(domStyle) {
    domStyle.set(dijit.byId("tabContainer").domNode, {'display': 'block'});
    dijit.byId("tabContainer").resize();
}`






p.s. - I know I should also edit `dijit.byId("tabContainer")` to `require(["dojo/dom-attr"], function(domAttr){});` but u get the point

Answer (score 6):

Old thread but I experienced this same issue and this is how I solved it. First, you cannot use display:none. Per the folks at DOJO, you have to use visibility:hidden with dijits or this will not work. So, you want this:

```
<div id="tabContainer" dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width:500px; height:100px;visibility:hidden;">
```

Then, to show this you do the following:

```
dojo.style("tabContainer", "visibility", "visible");
```

Now, the problem this poses is what you already found out. This reserves a invisible div in your viewport that is 500px wide. So if you are using a bordercontainer, there will be this empty 500px gap in your page. To resolve this, I had to create my dijits programatically and inject them into a empty div, rather than do what you did and do it declaratively. Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: @streetlight - Been a couple years since I worked with DOJO. You would just have to try it out. Sorry can't be more help.

Answer (score 4):

you should do

```
dijit.byId("tabContainer").domNode.style.display = 'block'
```

or perhaps

```
dijit.byId("tabContainer").domNode.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

is even better

Comment: the first option doesn't work, either. The second option, modified to be what I assume you intended ('visible' and not 'hidden') works a little bit better, but still not right. Using the visibility property makes the TabContainer hide and show properly, but it still takes up space on the page while hidden (an invisible box).

Comment: Well you could change the position to absolute. But that makes it kind of an ugly hack.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did not solve this problem, but I came up with a workaround...Creating the TabContainer on the click event, instead of creating it hidden on page load and then showing it on the click event.

HTML:

```
<div id="tabContainer">     
</div>
```

JS:

```
var tabContainer = new dijit.layout.TabContainer({id:"tabContainer", style:"width:500px;height:200px;"}, dojo.byId('tabContainer'));  
//add tabs
tabContainer.startup();
```

Answer (score 1):

After you set display:block do this:

```
dijit.byId('tabContainer').resize();
```

dijit.layout widgets often don't lay themselves out properly if they are display:none (and sometimes even when visibility:hidden).  You have to fiddle around in Firebug till you figure out what works!

Answer (score 1):

Tested sucessfully with **Dojo 1.10** . Use registry instead of "dijit.byId()". The method **resize()** only works on the **dijit.layout.BorderContainer**.

```
define([
    "dijit/registry" // registry
], function(registry) {

    var show = true;

    if (show) {
        domStyle.set(registry.byId("dijitLayoutContentPane").domNode, {'display': 'block'});
        registry.byId("dijitLayoutBorderContainer").resize();
    } else {
        domStyle.set(registry.byId("dijitLayoutContentPane").domNode, {'display': 'none'});
        registry.byId("dijitLayoutBorderContainer").resize();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing (setting `style.display = "none"`) is right. In place of

> ...then setting style.display = "block"

you should just call `.set_visible` JS method of the ajax TabContainer when "...user clicks a button", like:

```
$find('<%= Tabs.ClientID %>').set_visible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this after setting the style display:block and it works great! This way you don't need to know the ID of the container to resize.

`this.getParent().resize();`

Answer (score 0):

If you use
    dijit.byId("tabContainer").resize();
after you set the display to block it will bring back the tab headers.

You'll save a little bit of javascript if you just use 
    visibility: hidden;
(although the tabContainer will still take up space on the page)

Another alternative I use pretty frequently is instead of 
    display: none/block;
I use 
    height: 0px/auto;

You could also switch the position to absolute and set the coordinates for off screen somewhere too. That's require a lot more css changes than simply doing the height though. That's my preferred method if it works in my situation.

Between these solutions hopefully one will work for you.