# How to disable specific dijit contentPane tabs created by html?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using Dojo tabContainer & contentPane. I want a tab which cannot be opened by clicking on it. Is this possible? Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is not currently possible to do though the tabContainer implementation (see [here](http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/5601)) but you could try some of the things suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294444/how-to-disable-single-tab-in-dojo-tabcontainer)

A suggested workaround from the enchancement page  is :

> wildbill noticed that in _TabButton.html, there is a connection that is not set up properly. The onclick:onClick part of the outermost dojoAttachEvent should actually be onclick:_onClick
>
> So. With that fix in place, you can disable a tab using the original piece of code above. i.e. find the tab button by iterating over the registry and filtering it out. i.e.
>
> ```
> var b;
> ```
>
> dijit.registry.byClass("dijit.layout._TabButton").forEach(function(x)
>   {if (x.label=="your tab button's label") b = x;});
>
> ```
> //now disable it...
> b.setAttribute('disabled', true);
> ```